# c++ subclass access to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I am currently studying c++ and I have a question.
Inside the concept of inheritance, I understand that the subclass has the access to base class's data and method. 
But if the **Base class** implements an interface, can the subclass access or use the methods defined in the interface that is implemented in the **Base class**?

Comment: C++ is not Java. There is no such a thing *interface* in C++, it's same as a class.

Comment: You can have virtual class, that'll have pure virtual function only. That will be somewhat similar to interface implementation in java.

Comment: A subclass does not have automatic access to a base classes data and methods. But if a subclass can access a base class method, it makes no difference at all whether that method is part of an interface implementation. So I despite the wrong premise to your question I think the answer is YES.

Comment: If you use Java, your explanation is completely right. The concept of interface is just specification for class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. Suppose you have a Base class as following

```
class Base {
public:
   virtual void someMethod() {
   //Do your stuff
   }
};
```

And a derived class like the following

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
   void someMethod() override;
};
```

And the definition of `someMethod` in `Derived class` is as following

```
void Derived::someMethod() {
  // Do Derived Stuffs
  //Now you may call the Base::someMethod by following
  Base::someMethod();
}
```

You can try in this way.